# Taxonomy saving order on node

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

Coming from a different CMS, I am diving little by little into the Drupal philosophy and I have already bumped into a problem. (being a beginner sucks :/ )

I have installed the hierarchical select module to facilitate my user to add the taxonomies they want. But the user is not happy with the way that the list is displayed.

What I wanted to do is to find a way for the user to define the display (and thus the saving) order of the taxonomies on each node independently.

I thought of weights but that would have an impact on the taxonomy order and not the node.

I did a few searches on the fora and also googled a bit but I always go around the views related topics and I am not able to find a module that does this.

It might be impossible (I have no clue yet on how the taxonomies are saved and treated in the database) so I explain a bit more the situation as there might be a better solution or an alternative to what I am thinking.

In practice, my user wants to be able to choose out of a list of taxonomies one to be displayed before the others, and ideally to be able to arrange the rest of the terms at will.

eg.

```
node 1 -> Term3, term 2, term 5

node 2 -> Term1, term 5, term 6
```

The user suggested that could also "work" with 3 fields that define the order of the chosen terms but I find this solution very short term solution and will cause problems the day that I need to add a 4th or a nth field on the same node.

Any suggestion apart from creating my own module?

Thanks a lot for you input,

Comment: Not a big enough help to warrant an answer, but if you use Term References, that lets you define N taxonomy terms to be associated (via/like tagging) if you want. And I also think the order in which the references are defined is the order they display, so it should be fine. Term Reference fields should come out of the box.

Comment: Similarly there is an Entity Reference module that allows you to do the same thing, but having nodes reference other nodes, not just taxonomy terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input @JPMC. In the end I just used [Simple Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) and did what I wanted to do.